# How to set select to multiple select

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have select box with multiple select. I have an array with value. I want to set selected values of select field based on array.
I have an array

```
values=array("a","b","c","d","e");
```

And select field

```
    <select name="check[]" id="check" multiple> 
        <option value="">--- Select Document Type ----</option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
        <option value="d">d</option>
        <option value="e">e</option>
        <option value="f">f</option>
        <option value="g">g</option>
        <option value="h">h</option>
    </select>
```

I want options selected as per array.

Comment: not clear what is the issue?

Comment: I didnt understand. Do u want the array elements as ur dropdown options?

Comment: They say [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) should be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in_array()` in this case:

```
$values=array("a","b","c","d","e");
$select = range('a', 'h');

?>
<select name="check[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100px; height: 200px;">
    <?php foreach($select as $s): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $s; ?>" <?php echo in_array($s, $values) ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >
            <?php echo $s; ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

[Fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GMeNlF)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($values as $key=>$value)
    echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want. Check whether you want this

```
<?php
$values=array("a","b","c","d","e");
?>
<select name="check[]" id="check" multiple> 
        <option value="">--- Select Document Type ----</option>
        <?php
        foreach ($values as $x)
        {
            ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $x; ?>"><?php echo $x; ?></option>
             <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```